# Electric outlet on roof

Tags: electrical, receptacle, roof

I have a flat roof for my 1100 sqft home which I expect to replace or recover in a couple years.  I'm considering whether I should mount an outdoor gfci electrical outlet, just coming straight up [like this](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1436&bih=803&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=fpIyW84U-sPQ8Q-forOoDg&q=flat%20roof%20electrical%20outlet&oq=flat%20roof%20electrical%20outlet&gs_l=img.3...83684.86664.0.87031.10.10.0.0.0.0.181.663.9j1.10.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0....0.3FBP3NdubCs#imgrc=YUyk3Rc1ccqibM:).   Besides christmas lights, what other uses might I need it for?  Good idea, bad idea?

Comment: Your first question is too broad, and your second is completely subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have any HVAC equipment mounted on the roof, you are going to be REQUIRED to have a GFCI protected receptacle next to it for service equipment. But barring that, I wouldn't do it: no need for it,  waste of money, possible site for future leaks and then it will get in the way of the future re-roofing project.

Comment: Right, from a practical point of view the fewer holes you have on a roof the fewer possible leaks.

Comment: I left this part out: just use extension cords for the Christmas lights. Easily replaced, no roof penetrations, useful for other things.

Answer (score 3):

A better location, avoiding roof penetrations, better weather avoidance, and re-roofing complications, would be in your soffits. I power my gutter cables from them.  Run an extension cord for holiday lights or occasional power tools.

Comment: I agree with soffits, the outlet gets protected and there is no penetration flat roofs are hard enough to seal and Christmas lights can be connected easily.

Comment: Good thought but in my case, no soffit - I have a parapet wall which I think might be too short (4") for a convenient install